# Twitter scribe and clojure "The access_token method must be called with a request_token"

Tags: java, twitter, clojure, oauth-2.0, scribe

(NB If you don't understand clojure I can traslate the code in Java, just ask please)

I am using scribe with clojure and I am finding some issue to log in with twitter, the code I am using:

```
(def twitter-service
  (-> (doto
          (ServiceBuilder.)
        (.provider (TwitterApi$Authenticate.))
        (.apiKey "apikey")
        (.apiSecret "apisecret")
        (.callback "https://morgan-siscia.rhcloud.com/tatata/"))
      (.build)))

(def tokens (atom {}))

(defn get-token []
  (.getRequestToken twitter-service))

(defn get-twitter-url [token]
  (swap! tokens assoc (.getToken token) token)
  (.getAuthorizationUrl twitter-service token))

(defn get-info-twitter [oauth-token oauth-veri]
  (let [token (get @tokens oauth-token)
        verifier (Verifier. oauth-veri)
        access-token (.getAccessToken twitter-service token verifier)
        request (doto (OAuthRequest. (Verb/POST)
                                     "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")
                  (.addOAuthParameter "oauth_token" oauth-token)
                  (.addBodyParameter "oauth_verifier" oauth-veri))]
    (do
      (.signRequest twitter-service access-token request)
      (swap! tokens dissoc oauth-token))
    (.getBody (.send request))))
```

The code is pretty a straight translation of the java code, however it is not working.

When I call (get-info-twitter "the-oauth-code" "the verifier code") twitter return an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <request>/oauth/access_token</request>
  <error>The access_token method must be called with a request_token</error>
</hash>
```

Honestly I have no idea what I am doing wrong, can somebody help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how Twitter OAuth works (I do it with Twitter4j, principle should be the same for you) :

- you ask a **RequestToken** :

> RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

- From this, you get 2 objects : a **token** and a **tokenSecret** :

> String token = requestToken.getToken();
>       String secretToken = requestToken.getTokenSecret();

- User is authorizing your application and a **callback URL** is invoked by Twitter, passing you 2 parameters : **oauth_token** and **oauth_verifier**
- With these 2 parameters, you can ask an **AccessToken** :

> AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);

requestToken is rebuilt from previous token and secretToken saved somewhere

- This new object contains 2 String you have to keep for future calls to Twitter :

> credentials.token = accessToken.getToken();
>
> credentials.secret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();

I save this object in a database and reuse it for later calls to Twitter.
I had the same error as you when I did not understand well all these tokens everywhere.

Try to follow this step-by-step and it should work.

Comment: It is late here, but thanks to you I should get my error... I will check tomorrow morning... Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I was doing too much, I was getting the access token and try to get access to other resource using the wrong token... The scribe documentation is not so clear...

Comment: great explanation, I had written some code and it worked, until one day it stopped & doesn't work again. In database I've saved credentials.token & credentials.secret and now to update users's twitter status, I do as 

`RequestToken requestToken = new RequestToken(user.getTwittertoken(), user.getTwittersecret());
                        
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, user.getTwittersecret());`

I'm getting 401 - <error>The access_token method must be called with a request_token. Can you please help ? or share your code that updates it later.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use clojure-twitter? It would be cleaner.

Example:

```
(:require twitter [oauth.client :as oauth])

 ;; Make a OAuth consumer
 (def oauth-consumer (oauth/make-consumer 
                      twitter-key
                      twitter-secret
                      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
                      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
                      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
                      :hmac-sha1))
```

And then:

```
(twitter/with-oauth oauth-consumer
     oauth-access-token
     oauth-access-token-secret
     (print (twitter/user-timeline :screen-name username)))
```

https://github.com/mattrepl/clojure-twitter

Comment: Yeah, it would be but than I would need something for facebook, and then for G+...

Answer (score 0):

The `oauth_verifier` parameter comes in the callback. Use that one